# Port Forward to 27017 Amazon DocumentDB Cluster loads forever

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, portforwarding, aws-documentdb

I'm trying to configure a local port to forward connection to Amazon DocumentDB Cluster, but the command loads forever and don't get any error.

I'm following these instructions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-from-outside-a-vpc.html

**The command:**

```
ssh -i "rsa.pem" -L 27017:docdb.cluster-XXXXX.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 ubuntu@X.X.X.X -N
```

**Expect:**
Port forward created.

**Result:**
Command loading forever.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the command has actually succeeded, and the tunnel is available for use. Try connecting to `localhost:27017` to verify. (For example, open a separate terminal window and run `telnet localhost 27017`.)

(This is standard behavior for `ssh -N`; when it succeeds, it doesn't show any output and the command can look like it's just hanging.)